# using file command in bash script error using variable

Tags: bash

I have a file named "file" in my current directory. I want to check the type of this using file command and variables. I created this script:

```
name="file"
file $name
```

but it is giving this error:

```
: cannot open `file\015\015' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: `\015` is the octal value of carriage return. So you need to remove the carriage returns from the `$name` variable.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: or just remove the cr's before doing anything in it on Unix like system. hint `dos2unix` is the easiest if available.

Comment: Generally, avoid using a Windows editor to edit scripts, or figure out how to configure it to save these files with correct line endings for the destination platform.

Answer (score -3):

I think the problem is that you named your file as `file`.

So rename your file as file2, then

```
name="file2"
file $name
```

**Explanation**

The problem with the name `file` is bash is trying to RUN your file against itself, when you have your current directory in your PATH.

Comment: Are you sure about that? `echo bar > file; name=file; file "$name"`  the output `file: ASCII text`

Comment: If you put 2 CR in your `file`, what should you get ? I bet again its "ASCII text"

Comment: So whats the point on renaming `file` to `file2`?

Comment: And to answer that question: `printf 'DOS\r\nline endings\r\n' > file; name=file; file "$name"`  output:     `file: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: That's not what is happening. Whatever you put after a command name is passed as an argument to that command. Except if variable expansions or shell expansions are found, in which case they get evaluated before being converted into parameters by the shell. However, nothing special is going here.

Comment: jfyi, It is not my down vote, I tried to explain that to you...